# Python module to compute stationary distribution of Markov chain

Tags: python, markov-process

Is there any module for Python that computes the stationary distribution of a Markov chain, given the generator matrix?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy.linalg.eig of the matrix's transpose to find a left eigenvector.

Alternatively, you could use the numpy matrix class, and raise it to any high enough power (and actually see it converge, along the way.